# Working with file directories and variables

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory

I have a program that I want to make more dynamic. The current setup is literally typing everything out.

I would like the program to work with a for loop (any other suggestions would be great). My goal is to loop through a specific file that has sub-directories and get the name of each folder (sub-directory),  then get the name of the files within the sub-directory.

To put this in a file string:
C:\Folder 1\Folder 2\File name

From the above, I would like to get the value of `Folder 2` and `File name`.

My code so far:

```
for sub_dir in os.listdir(r"C:\Folder 1\"):
    DIR = r'' + sub_dir
    files_found = len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, name))])
    if(files_found > 0):
        for files in os.listdir(sub_dir):
            file_name = os.path.splitext(files)[0]
```

I get the error --> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: `Folder 2`

I appreciate your efforts to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [os.walk](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

It recursively traverses a file tree, returning a list of all directories and files within a directory at each step.